# If $n = 4k$ where $k$ is odd, and $n-1>m>n/2+1$ , then $m^2$ isn't $1$ modulo $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

After looking at a few examples, I believe the statement above is true, but I don't know how to prove it. I have this: you can show $(n/2+1)^2$ is 1 modulo $n$. If $m = n/2+1+k$, where $k<n/2-1$, then it follows that $k^2+2k\equiv 0\mod(n).$ From this you get that $\frac {k}{2}(\frac{k}{2}+1) =qn/4$ for some $q$. I don't know how to proceed from here.

If you know of a result like this or maybe a more general one, I would like to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only true if $k$ is a prime power.

If $k$ has two distinct odd prime factors, you can always find a counterexample.

If $k=p^a,$ where $p$ is an odd prime and $a>0,$ then there are only two solutions to  $$m^2\equiv1\pmod k$$ and thus only $4$ solutions to $$m^2\equiv 1\pmod{n}.$$
Those four solutions are $1,2k-1,2k+1,4k-1.$

But when $k$ has two odd prime factors, then there are at least $8$ solutions to $$m^2\equiv 1\pmod{4k},$$ and one of them will be in the range, because if $m$ is a solution then $n-m$ is a solution.

If $$k=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_j^{a_j}$$ is odd, then there are $2^{j+1}$ distinct values $m,$ modulo $4k,$ such that $m^2\equiv 1\pmod {4k}.$ This means that there must be $2^j-2$ roots in the range.

You can find the $2^{j+1}$ roots by solving the $2^{j+1}$ Chinese Remainder Theorem congruence:

$$\begin{align}my&\equiv\pm1\pmod{4}\\
m&\equiv\pm1\pmod{p_1^{a_1}}\\
&\vdots\\
m&\equiv \pm1\pmod{p_j^{a_j}}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

An ease computer search gives several counterexamples. Take, for example, $n=60$ and $m=41$.

Here are all the counterexamples with $n<200$

\begin{array}{cc}
 n & m \\
 60 & 41 \\
 60 & 49 \\
 84 & 55 \\
 84 & 71 \\
 132 & 89 \\
 132 & 109 \\
 140 & 99 \\
 140 & 111 \\
 156 & 103 \\
 156 & 131 \\
 180 & 109 \\
 180 & 161 \\
\end{array}

Comment: Yeah, it might be true if $k$ is a prime power, but not for any other $k.$